# find pricing information for a GCE instance given machine type, region and commitment type

Tags: google-compute-engine

I use the GCP metadata API (http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/) to get information about the instance that a process is running on, including machine type (e.g. "projects/818238156224/machineTypes/n1-standard-4" -- presumably the important part is the "n1-standard-4"), region, zone, and whether the instance is preemptible.

I would like to be able to retrieve information programmatically about how much GCP is charging (e.g. per hour) for usage of the instance.

I can query the GCP billing API (https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus), but that returns JSON like

```json
{
    "name": "services/6F81-5844-456A/skus/0048-21CE-74C3",
    "skuId": "0048-21CE-74C3",
    "description": "Preemptible N2 Custom Instance Core running in Sao Paulo",
    "category": {
        "serviceDisplayName": "Compute Engine",
        "resourceFamily": "Compute",
        "resourceGroup": "CPU",
        "usageType": "Preemptible"
    },
    "serviceRegions": [
        "southamerica-east1"
    ],
    "pricingInfo": [
        {
            "summary": "",
            "pricingExpression": {
                "usageUnit": "h",
                "usageUnitDescription": "hour",
                "baseUnit": "s",
                "baseUnitDescription": "second",
                "baseUnitConversionFactor": 3600,
                "displayQuantity": 1,
                "tieredRates": [
                    {
                        "startUsageAmount": 0,
                        "unitPrice": {
                            "currencyCode": "USD",
                            "units": "0",
                            "nanos": 11538000
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "currencyConversionRate": 1,
            "effectiveTime": "2021-05-26T08:47:05.220Z"
        }
    ],
    "serviceProviderName": "Google",
    "geoTaxonomy": {
        "type": "REGIONAL",
        "regions": [
            "southamerica-east1"
        ]
    }
}
```

And it's very unclear how to retrieve an objects in one API given an object in the other.

Do I need to parse the description somehow? Does that even work? Is there a better way?

Comment: Enable exporting your billing information to BigQuery. Then query BigQuery for details. The Billing service does not have an API to fetch this information. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery

Comment: Exporting our own billing information isn't going to help. We build an agent that runs on our clients' instances and analyzes their billing data for them.

Comment: Exporting billing information to BigQuery is the only method Google offers today.

Comment: This seems like a feature request for Google, so I've raised it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/190036249